# Are swagger models equal to classes in the system

Tags: rest, oop, swagger

I'm new to Swagger. I was able to document the API with swagger, but I'm not clear about the models.

swagger model - User

```
User:
 type: object
 properties:
   uuid:
     type: string
   name:
     type: string
   role:
     type: string
   author:
     $ref: '#/definitions/User'
```

User class from the DB

[image]

here, the structure is the same.

But, if we want to send some extra details ( example:- userEdited : boolean) of the user via the API, we may have to change the User model in swagger. Am I correct? If not how to properly handle this scenario?